# Onboarding a new client in an existing CQRS architecture

Tags: nservicebus, cqrs

I'm architecting a new solution for a small business of maybe ten machines. The business is so small, they don't even have a server per-se that runs 24/7, so, choosing NServiceBus/RavenDB seemed like an obvious choice for reliable, queued operations, and so I could practice developing a server that did not amount to (more or less) a glorified repository from the client perspective.

The design I have so far is one server and many clients. On day one, commands are handled and events are sent indicating that the state of object X, Y, or Z has changed, allowing clients the opportunity to update their local RavenDB caches for reliable, instant querying. The problem I can't seem to solve, however, is what happens when the business decides to onboard a new machine in the future? This new machine did not start on Day 0 and thus does not have a screenshot from which to synchronize state with all other machines.

To be sure, my server is saving "screenshots" by way of a typical SQL database, in case the server goes down, but how do I convey these screenshots appropriately to a new client in a (almost pure) CQRS solution?

Should the client send a command asking for a giant screenshot from which to start?

Should I clone a cache from another client for the new client's first day?

Should the client have the ability to connect to the server's SQL database directly to assimilate its own screenshot where necessary?

Is it considered unclean/impure to allow the client to connect to the server's persistence store when trying to achieve some semblance of event sourcing? (In this case, I'm not storing audit tables of the events, but rather relying on clients to project events into their cache which effects event sourcing.)

Comment: I think your problem is similar to that of occasionally connected clients, here is a article which talks about solutions for such scenarios http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650163.aspx ...

Answer (score 0):

If you implement `IWantToRunWhenTheBusStarts` you could round trip out to your SQL source to pull state locally.  Since the service may get restarted you'll just have to make sure that you pull the correct data set.  This may also help in situations where the client becomes disconnected for a period of time.

Comment: So you're advocating for allowing the client to connect directly to the server for a current screenshot? I would think CQRS was about avoiding such a thing, right? But then again, how else do you make screenshots available to clients? Sending a specific event?

Comment: What about using replication to synchronise the various data sources?

Comment: The solution I recommended is strictly just for on-boarding new clients.  The rest of the time you would follow the normal communication process.  This would run once upon start up.

Comment: It would seem the most practical solution is to offline a client and clone its cache to the new machine for its day 0 with the server. Creating messages for the sole purpose of delivering snapeshots from server to client would seem to defeat the purpose of CQRS IMO.

Comment: I'm proposing the same solution you are(cloning the cache), I'm just offering a place to have that code execute and bundle it into the app so that your deployment process isn't affected.